# Silverlight Background Thread using WebClient

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm using a `WebClient` to get infos asynchronously from my web service :

```
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCompleted;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(service);
```

I works fine, but I think the `DownloadStringCompleted` method is working on the UI Thread, and since i'm doing a lot of parsing there, my page takes a few seconds to appear. However, since I have so fixed data and a progress bar, I would'nt mind have it appearing instantly.

How could I perfom this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HttpWebRequest` rather than `WebClient`. HWR doesn't return on the UI thread and so doesn't block it from updating.

Comment: Demonstrated here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8

Comment: does WebClient return on the UI thread or calling thread? say you call  wc.DownloadStringAsync(service); from a background thread, does it still come back to the UI thread? (on wp7)

Comment: @coderguy123 yes, in the example `service` will run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` does indeed return on the UI thread so yes your parsing will be blocking the UI.  For perf reasons it is [recommended](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/10/26/wp7-development-tips-part-1.aspx) that you use `HttpWebRequest` instead.

With `HttpWebReques`t your event will fire on the background thread so you can do all the processing you need, however you then have the problem of marshaling the results back to the UI thread so that you can update the UI (otherwise you will see cross thread violation exceptions).  You can use the `Dispatcher` to marshal the results back to the UI with a method like the following:

```
private void UpdateUI(Results results)
{
    if (!Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UpdateUI(results));
    else
    {
        //Update the UI
    {
}
```

Comment: There is no need to call CheckAccess. Just simply call BeginInvoke. Also recursion is not the best as well. Get rid off exclamation mark and swap the statments for cleaner code.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the UpdateUI method will not also be called on the UI thread so it's not certain if BeginInvoke is required or not.  For perf reasons we don't want to call BeginInvoke unnecessarily - it probably won't make much of a difference for a one off but as a pattern it's not a good idea.

Comment: As for the exclamation mark ordinarily I would agree but in this case it is preferable to have the code listed in the order it actually is going to execute. Switching the statements, as you suggest would have the code that is likely to execute first be at the bottom of the method which would be even more confusing.

Nevertheless thanks for the impromptu code review!

Comment: What is even worse, imho, is premature optimization. I would never complicate code like this, unless I have actually measured that it makes the execution significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

In Mango the WebClient is changed so that if the

```
wc.DownloadStringAsync(service);
```

call is made from the background thread the response also comes to the background thread. You can use the BackgroundWorker to achieve this.